# clickonce deployment with prerequisites

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

We have an application that we deploy to a website.  User goes to the website and downloads the application to their machine.
There are a few prerequisites such as .net and sql server 2012 express that we just click in the "prereqs" to install.  But we also have another executable file syncronization which is an exe that the user needs to install before loading the application.  How can we also include that so before the app runs it loads this as well. because i don't see an option to include it, it just has the standard default microsoft ones.

Comment: Take a look at [How to: Include Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130.aspx) and [Creating Bootstrapper Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)

Comment: is there any other way to just download the executable from the server website? just like the other ones were downloaded from microsoft website

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to run a .exe file along with your main app???
Or it is like the .exe file should load before when you start the main app????

Comment: Its a prereq. Sync framework exe that installs before the app installs. One time thing